How do I access a local docker registry from another deployment?
I have the following registry service that I can push to using docker push
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: registry
spec:
  selector:
    app: registry
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30500
  type: NodePort

$ docker push 10.0.0.58:30500/block-party:latest
The push refers to repository [10.0.0.58:30500/block-party]
e0cd0596ba65: Layer already exists
b80974699bdb: Layer already exists
3f69a32a2b31: Layer already exists
d75fd41110a4: Layer already exists
2e0d92876e9f: Layer already exists
a8a738834a4d: Layer already exists
bf6cd01dee5e: Layer already exists
52ec5a4316fa: Layer already exists
latest: digest: sha256:6923ac9281f4ed9c5c2fdb1e70acf906d014a104f130f04bcc7878793f8a3479 size: 1988

Now I would like to use the dependency so I try
~$ sudo microk8s.ctr images pull registry.network.svc.cluster.local:5000/block-party:latest
[sudo] password for partyk1d24:
INFO[0000] trying next host                              error="failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.network.svc.cluster.local:5000/v2/block-party/manifests/latest\": dial tcp: lookup registry.network.svc.cluster.local on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving" host="registry.network.svc.cluster.local:5000"
ctr: failed to resolve reference "registry.network.svc.cluster.local:5000/block-party:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry.network.svc.cluster.local:5000/v2/block-party/manifests/latest": dial tcp: lookup registry.network.svc.cluster.local on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving

It seems the problem here is it is using https instead of http and I see in the instructions there is the possibility to use insecure
https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-private#configuring-microk8s
But even trying to create
/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/certs.d/registry.network.svc.cluster.local:5000/hosts.toml
I still get the same error. What am I missing?
I also tried using the external port
~$ cat /var/snap/microk8s/current/args/certs.d/10.0.0.58:30500/hosts.toml
server = "http://10.0.0.58:30500"

[host."http://10.0.0.58:30500"]
capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]

But still get the same, it tries to use https

I do not know mikrok8s, but it looks very clearly to be a DNS problem. registry.network.svc.cluster.local should resolve to an IP where you can access things on :5000. The docker https problem did not access you yet, but also that will.

@peterh the question isn't why am I getting an issue it is how do I get microk8s to use http instead of https for the registry. Accessing the registry from either environment (local or on microk8s) is fine if http is used instead
